# LaTeX support in Mobile Application

Tags: discussion, android-app, latex

This could be seen either as a bug or a discussion point, but the long and short is: **TeX is busted in the mobile application**.

[image]

I understand that it's a heavy requirement, but the support for TeX is already widespread throughout the different platforms—so much so that even the mobile browsers support it (it just takes a while for it to load). It would be very nice to have this same level of support in the mobile app.

Comment: As you mentioned - this is a desire of ours but one we have punted on for the moment.  This is a HUGE project.

Comment: Wow.. yes, this is both INTERESTING and HUGE... Are you planning to do it on the server (pre-rendering latex as images), on the client (using a Java library http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41609/tex-rendering-in-a-java-application), or re-using your JS library in Android somehow?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas: Could you perhaps make the app open the browser when the user tries to open a math.stackexchange page? Because for math.stackexchange LaTeX is really essential.

Comment: Please do *not* implement what moose said...  As a nearly exclusively Math.SE user, it would nearly defeat the purpose of the app for me.  I can sight-read most LaTeX, anyway (and I'd wager many Math.SE users can as well), so I'd rather leave the questions opening in the app, rather than opening in a browser.