# LaTeX doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, latex

LaTeX is not working just now. I posted this question, and the LaTeX code is plainly rendered as ASCII.

[R: There is a more elegant/efficient way of writing this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259324/r-there-is-a-more-elegant-efficient-way-of-writing-this)

(possibly a duplicate of this one

[LaTeX support in Mobile Application](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192356/latex-support-in-mobile-application)

but I also see it on PC, and I didn't check on a phone)

Edit: I edited the linked post to remove Latex code, and used unicode instead.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30559/274942 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/274942, and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LaTeX on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to [Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606/350567):

Stack Overflow isn't in the list, so no mathJax there.

Mathjax is quite dependency-heavy and can slow down the load time of *every* page ([more on the performance issues here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-on-stack-overflow/60020#60020)), so there hasn't been enough need demonstrated on Stack Overflow to burden everyone with that overhead.